# Mysql error after upgrade to 8, only_full_group_by error

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, mysql-error-1055

This line give me the error:

> Error: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and
>   contains nonaggregated column 'hng_1.tags.id' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
foreach($groups as $group)
    {
            $query = mysqli_query($verbindung, "SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(id) AS c FROM tags WHERE typ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($verbindung, $group) . "' GROUP BY slug ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 9) AS i ORDER BY i.tag ASC") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($verbindung));

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $tmp_tags[] = $row;
            }
    }
```

How can I change the query to fix this error?

Comment: Your query makes little sense.  Maybe show us what your expected output is and we can help you.  Good to see the new MySQL 8 only full group by message doing a better job explaining what is happening.

Comment: What you want a query to do? That includes giving the constraints on input & how the output is to be a function of the input. What did you think the old one did? Have you read the group by documentation to see what it actually does? Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Learn how to do `GROUP BY`.  Your query is not valid, that's why it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is interested, I solved this problem. I added id to GROUP BY so it now know what to select.

```
GROUP BY slug, id
```

fix it.